# I have a problem in my activity_main_land.xml, it displays the following error: element LinearLayout must be declared

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem in my activity_main_land.xml, it displays the following error:
element LinearLayout must be declared, Namespace declaration is never used

this is my code below

```html
<Linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.derek.myspeedalerter.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/setspeed_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.derek.myspeedalerter.SetSpeedFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/setspeed_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/display_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.derek.myspeedalerter.DisplayFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/display_fragment" />
</Linearlayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have activity_main_land.xml in the res/layout folder? Namespace declaration is never used is just a warning, because you have xmlns:tools imported, even you don't use it.

Comment: its not in the the res/layout folder. I put it in a different folder in res/layout_land.